# How to create a compile time const string "n" characters long for NUnit Testcase

Tags: c#, string, nunit, compile-time-constant

Using NUnit I want to test whether given string is shorter than 200 characters.
My goal is not to hard-code this string, because I will have a string with 201 characters as counter-part in another test.

Lets look at the test signature:

```
[TestCase("GetTooLongName")]
public void If_NameIsTooLong_ReturnError(string name)
```

I have tried to use a string constructor that takes 2 params, a char and number of times it will be concatenated. I tried to get it from field and from function:

```
private static readonly string GetTooLongName = new('x', 201);
private static string LongNameStillOk => new('x', 200);
```

In the end I get an error:

```
An attribute must be a constant expression...
```

Is there a nice and  clean way to provide such long string to test attribute?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You can only use compile time constants.

Comment: You can make constants refer to other constants. So you could eg do `const string char1 = "x"; const string char10 = char1 + char1 + char1 + char1 + char1 + char1 + char1 + char1 + char1 + char1; const string char100 = char10 + char10 + char10 + char10 + char10 + char10 + char10 + char10 + char10 + char10;` etc

Comment: This wouldn't though solve the main problem, which is to make it in a clean and nice way.
I could obviously declare it as "xxxxxxxxxxxx..." and it would be more simple than solution with adding chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have used `TestCaseSource` attribute of NUnit.

The code appears as follows:

```
private const int MAX_ALLOWED_STRING_LENGTH = 200;
private static string[] _nameTooLongSource= {new('x', MAX_ALLOWED_STRING_LENGTH + 1)};

[TestCaseSource(nameof(_nameTooLongSource))]
public void If_NameIsTooLong_ReturnError(string name)
```

This then creates a scenario for each of the elements of `_nameTooLongSource` array. It has only one element which is the long string.